# I keep an error around the '=' sign in the WHERE line and I can't figure it out

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT unitcp_qual_var.instance_id," & _
                          "*FROM qualified_data INNER JOIN unitcp_qual_var ON qualified_data.unit_id = unitcp_qual_var.unit_id AND qualified_data.baseline_id = unitcp_qual_var.baseline_id AND qualified_data.qualified_id = unitcp_qual_var.qualified_id" & _
                          "WHERE (qualified_data.unit_id = 19419) AND (unitcp_qual_var.port_id = 1) AND (qualified_data.unit_id = 19419) AND (qualified_data.baseline_id = 2) AND (qualified_data.mdu_id = 622) AND (unitcp_qual_var.instance_id = 2);")
                          ' "ORDER BY qualified_data.das_time Asc;")
```

Comment: IT's because you don't have a space between `unitcp_qual_var.qualified_id` and `WHERE` after those two lines concatenate.  Just stick an extra space in there so it concatenates properly `" WHERE (qualified_data.....`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick rewrite adding the required space between your `ON` conditions and your `WHERE` clause as well as incorporating the `ORDER BY`. I'm adding a variable to hold the SQL string so it can be dumped to your immediate/debug window so you can see the output and test instead of dealing with tricky error messages:

```
strSQL="SELECT unitcp_qual_var.instance_id, *" & _
  " FROM qualified_data INNER JOIN unitcp_qual_var ON qualified_data.unit_id = unitcp_qual_var.unit_id AND qualified_data.baseline_id = unitcp_qual_var.baseline_id AND qualified_data.qualified_id = unitcp_qual_var.qualified_id" & _
  " WHERE (qualified_data.unit_id = 19419) AND (unitcp_qual_var.port_id = 1) AND (qualified_data.unit_id = 19419) AND (qualified_data.baseline_id = 2) AND (qualified_data.mdu_id = 622) AND (unitcp_qual_var.instance_id = 2)" & _
  " ORDER BY qualified_data.das_time Asc;"

'dump out to immediate window/pane (View>>Immediate  to activate)
debug.print strSQL

'Run the sql into rs recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
```